# How can I sort a bar graph from highest to lowest in R? (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

How can I sort a bar graph from highest to lowest in R? (ggplot2)

the code is this, but feel free to do a better code haha 
Ps: it is a huge data

```
ggplot(kiva, aes(repayment_interval, loan_amount, fill = repayment_interval)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Total of loan for different types of repayment intervals")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want highest to lowest y-variable, `loan_amount`.

Difficult to answer without example data but something like this should work, using `reorder`. Also `geom_col` = less typing.

```
ggplot(kiva, 
       aes(reorder(repayment_interval, -loan_amount), loan_amount), 
           fill = repayment_interval)) + 
geom_col() +
ggtitle("Total of loan for different types of repayment intervals")
```